# Hashmap in for loop not reading all the input

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

This is for AOC day 2. The input is something along the lines of

"6-7 z: dqzzzjbzz

13-16 j: jjjvjmjjkjjjjjjj

5-6 m: mmbmmlvmbmmgmmf

2-4 k: pkkl

16-17 k: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkqf

10-16 s: mqpscpsszscsssrs

..."

It's formatted like 'min-max letter: password' and seperated by line. I'm supposed to find how many passwords meet the minimum and maximum requirements. I put all that prompt into a string variable and used `Pattern.quote("\n")` to seperate the lines into a string array. This worked fine. Then, I replaced all the letters except for the numbers and '-' by making a pattern `Pattern.compile("[^0-9]|-");` and running that for every index in the array and using `.trim()` to cut off the whitespace at the end and start of each string. This is all working fine, I'm getting the desired output like `6 7` and `13 16`.

However, now I want to try and split this string into two. This is my code:

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> numbers = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        
        String [] xArray = x[i].split(Pattern.quote(" "));
        int z = Integer.valueOf(xArray[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf(xArray[1]);
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(y);
        numbers.put(z, y);

    }
    
System.out.println(numbers);
```

So, first making a hasmap which will store <min, max> values. Then, the for loop (which runs 1000 times) splits every index of the `6 7` and `13 16` string into two, determined by the " ". The `System.out.println(z);` and `System.out.println(y);` are working as intended.

```
6
7
13
16
...
```

This output goes on to give me 2000 integers seperated by a line each time. That's exactly what I want. However, the `System.out.println(numbers);` is outputting:

```
{1=3, 2=10, 3=4, 4=7, 5=6, 6=9, 7=12, 8=11, 9=10, 10=18, 11=16, 12=13, 13=18, 14=16, 15=18, 16=18, 17=18, 18=19, 19=20}
```

I have no idea where to even start with debugging this. I made a test file with an array that is formatted like "even, odd" integers all the way up to 100. Using this exact same code (I did change the variable names), I'm getting a better output. It's not exactly desired since it starts at `350=351` and then goes to like `11=15` and continues in a non-chronological order but at least it contains all the 100 keys and values.

Also, completely unrelated question but is my formatting of the for loop fine? The extra space at the beginning and the end of the code?

Edit: I want my expected output to be something like `{6=7, 13=16, 5=6, 2=4, 16=17...}`. Basically, the hashmap would have the minimum and maximum as the key and value and it'd be in chronological order.

Comment: Advent of code puzzle inputs vary by user, so your link doesn't help anyone else to know what inputs you're using. My initial guess is that your inputs may include multiple copies of each `z` value, so a pair that you encounter later (6=9) is overwriting the pair you added to begin with (6=7). But without seeing inputs I can't verify that.

Comment: You should provide the problem or a short summary with sample input and expected output. The link you posted is only available for logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to put in a nail with a saw. A hashmap is not the right tool to achieve what you want, since

- Keys are unique. If you try to input the same key multiple times, the first input will be overwritten
- The order of items in a HashMap is undefined.
- A hashmap expresses a key-value-relationship, which does not exist in this context

A better datastructure to save your Passwords would probably just be a `ArrayList<IntegerPair>` where you would have to define IntegerPair yourself, since java doesn't have the notion of a type combining two other types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating the task unnecessarily. I would proceed as follows:

1. split the input using the line separator
2. for each line remove `:` and split using the spaces to get an array with length 3
3. build from the array in step two

   3.1. the min/max char count from array[0]

   3.2 charachter classes for the letter and its negation

   3.3 remove from the password all letters that do not correspond to the given one and check if the length of the password is in range.

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){   
    String input =  "6-7 z: dqzzzjbzz\n" +
                    "13-16 j: jjjvjmjjkjjjjjjj\n" +
                    "5-6 m: mmbmmlvmbmmgmmf\n" +
                    "2-4 k: pkkl\n" +
                    "16-17 k: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkqf\n" +
                    "10-16 s: mqpscpsszscsssrs\n";
    int count = 0;
    for(String line : input.split("\n")){
        String[] temp = line.replace(":", "").split(" ");         //[6-7, z, dqzzzjbzz]
        String minMax = "{" + (temp[0].replace('-', ',')) + "}";  //{6,7}
        String letter = "[" + temp[1] + "]";                      //[z]
        String letterNegate = "[^" + temp[1] + "]";               //[^z]       
        if(temp[2].replaceAll(letterNegate, "").matches(letter + minMax)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count + "passwords are valid");
}
```